# cannot find crt1.o /crti.o /libpthread.so.0 after Raspi cross compiled with Qt

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3

Finally I did cross compiling using Qt5.10, and stretch for Pi3, through Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit using this wiki https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS

After I configured Qt and run some projects like open Qt Widgets screen and adding some labels on it it was working good, I was able to see the compiled output on Raspi screen.

However now I start to build a real project, I run qmake for it, it exited normally.

when I run build, I get this weird error in the compile output panel!!

```
/home/a-mathias/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:275: recipe for target '_arm/out/exe/project_final
/home/a-mathias/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/home/a-mathias/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
/home/a-mathias/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread_nonshared.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [_arm/out/exe/project_final] Error 1
10:24:33: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project project_final (kit: Rpi3B)
When executing step "Make"
```

issues script!

```
:-1: error: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
:-1: error: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
:-1: error: cannot find /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
:-1: error: cannot find /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread_nonshared.a
:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I hope if any one can advice !!

Comment: Qt10? We got a time traveler here xD - you propably meant Qt 5.10? Also, have you checked if these libraries do exist in your sysroot?

Comment: :) yes i mean 5.10 :p ,

Comment: you were correct the sysroot was wrong, I fix it and problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Felix advice the sysroot was wrong, I fix it and problem solved